# Assign two functions to class?

Tags: python, function, class

```
class Math:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def add(self, add_num):
        return self.number + add_num

    def sub(self, sub_num):
        return self.number - sub_num
```

**Math(5).add(5)**

I get 10 as expected

But if I do `Math(5).add(5).sub(3)`:
I get this error `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sub'`

Comment: `add` returns an integer. If you want to chain calls, you want you method to return an instance of `Math`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for that to work your mehtods need to return `self` (or a fresh instance of  `Math`):

```
class Math:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def add(self, add_num):
        self.number += add_num
        return self
        # or:
        # return Math(self.number + add_num)

    def sub(self, sub_num):
        self.number -= sub_num
        return self
        # or:
        # return Math(self.number - add_num)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.number)

m = Math(5).add(5).sub(3)
print(m)
# 7
```

the `add` here now behaves more like an [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__).

Comment: I get `<__main__.Math at 0x1a144fe55f8>` when I only type `Math(5).add(5).sub(3)` without assigning and printing it. (I'm using Notebook)

Comment: @Chipmunkafy That's because your class doesn't implement `__repr__`.

Comment: @Chipmunkafy note that i added `__str__` to your class. as mentioned by Aran-Fey you may have to implement `__repr__` as well (you could use the same code to start).

Answer (score 2):

Of course.

What you do is essentially

```
a = Math(5) # a is a "Math" object
b = a.add(5) # b is what add() returns, i. e. an int
c = b.sub(3) # an int has no sub() method
```

I don't know what exactly you want to achieve: do you want add() and sub() to modify the object you are operating on? In this case, you can do

```
class Math:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def add(self, add_num):
        self.number = self.number + add_num
        return self

    def sub(self, sub_num):
        self.number = self.number - sub_num
        return self
```

If you don't want that, you can do instead

```
class Math:

    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def add(self, add_num):
        return Math(self.number + add_num)

    def sub(self, sub_num):
        return Math(self.number - sub_num)

        return self
```

In both cases, your intended way of chaining the calls works.

Answer (score 0):

The value that you return is not an object of your `Math` class.
You must create an object of `Math` whose `number` attribute is your computed results and return that for your code to work.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute `return self.number + add_num`, you return an integer, not an instance of your Math class. To solve this, you can change your add method to
`return Math(self.number + add_num)`.